# KeepMyFamilySecureLSP64.dll is crashing my GTA 5

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

If I try to delete it, it comes up with this error:

`Action cannot be completed because the file is opened in services.exe.`

But when I open services it says it's off.

Comment: How'd you install the game?

Comment: Do you have Kaspersky antivirus? It seems that .dll is related to it somehow.

Comment: @Frank I used rockstar installler

Comment: @TimmyJim Nope i dont have it

Comment: CMON SOMEBODY HELP ME!!

Comment: @Dr.Sheldon-Memer The error you're getting is due to that file being in use elsewhere on the PC. (Which in turn means that it's very likely not GTA 5 related) What information do you have that's telling you that file needs to be deleted to "fix" GTA 5?

Comment: @NBN-Alex I saw it in Event Viewer

Answer (score 5):

KeepMyFamilySecureLSP64.dll is a part of a parental control software called, unsurprisingly, "Keep my family secure".

Ask whoever controls the PC to disable said parental control software.

Comment: Asked my dad does he control it he said no and my mom doesnt know how to even do it... I trust my dad when he says no because he aint an expert either at it. And i have no parental controls over my PC ;p